# Problem parsing values in a Multi-step form using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, forms

Working on a multi-step form which has got 3 phases. In phase 1 the user fills a form which is submitted to the backend for validation, some data computation and later passed to the 2nd phase where the user triggers a button which has a dynamic id. Next, I use AJAX to fetch the values the user entered in the 1st phase of the form and the unique id of the button clicked by the user in the 2nd phase to a final controller.

The problem is the AJAX request aint picking the values from the 1st phase of the form when I try using **dd($quote)** as shown in the code below.

**Phase 1**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('b2c.getplans') }}" class="form-contact"  accept-charset="UTF-8">

        <div class="form-line{{ $errors->has('FirstName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

          <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="{{ old('FirstName') }}" required>
          <label>First Name *</label>
          <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
          <div class="check-label"></div>
           @if ($errors->has('FirstName'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('FirstName') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-line{{ $errors->has('MiddleName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="MiddleName" id="MiddleName"  value="{{ old('MiddleName') }}" required>
          <label>Middle Name *</label>
          <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
          <div class="check-label"></div>
          @if ($errors->has('MiddleName'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('MiddleName') }}</strong>
                </span>
          @endif
        </div>

    <div class="form-line registar love {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" style="margin-left: 0px;">
      <input type="text-area" id="email" class="form-input" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
      <label>Email *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
       @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="phone" id="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required>
      <label>Phone Number *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('phone'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="date" class="form-input" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required>
      <label>Date of Birth *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('dob'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="form-b3c" style="cursor:pointer;"> Get Plans</button>

  </form>
```

**2nd phase of the form**

```
@if (!empty($plans_benefits))
    <div class="container">
        <div class="PLAN">
            <main class="top">
                <div class="row">
              @foreach ($plans_benefits as $plan_benefits)
                @php
                  $plan_data = $plan_benefits[0];
                  $benefits = $plan_benefits[1];
                  $plan_name = $plan_data->Calculation_TravelPlan->TravelPlan->Name;
                @endphp   
                  <div class="card plan">
                        <h5 class="card-title plan"> {{$plan_name}} </h5>
                            <img class="card-img-top plan" src="{{asset('assets/images-new/superior.svg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="travel-plan">
                  <div class="superior-content">
                        <table class="table">
                          <tbody>
                            @foreach($benefits as $benefit)
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="plan-title">{{$benefit->name}}</td>
                                    @if($benefit->value == 'true')
                                        <td class="plan-worth"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                                    @elseif ($benefit->value == 'false')
                                        <td class="plan-worth"><i class="fas"></i></td>
                                    @else
                                        <td class="plan-worth"> {{$benefit->value}} </td>
                                    @endif
                                </tr>
                             @endforeach
                           </tbody>
                        </table> 
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <!-- Hiden-->
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"" class ="calc_id" name="calc_id" id="calc_id{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"/>

                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$plan_name}}" class ="travelplan" name="travelplan" id="plan{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"/>
                    <!--Hidden-->

                      <p class="card-text plan">TOTAL
                        <span class="amount">$  {{round($plan_data->TravelBasicPremium,2)}} 
                        </span>
                      </p>
                      <!-- AJAX call when the button is hit-->
                       <a id ="{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}" class="plan-quote get_quote" style="cursor:pointer;"><span>Get Quote</span></a>
                    </div>
                     </div>
    @endforeach
      </div>
            </main>
        </div>
  </div>
@endif
```

**AJAX code to fetch values when the button in the 2nd phase is hit**

```
$('.PLAN').on('click', '.get_quote', function () {
                //Fetch inputs from form
                var inputs = $(".form-contact :input");
                var calc_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var c_id = $('#calc_id' + calc_id).val();
                var plan_name = $('#plan' + calc_id).val();
                var entries = inputs.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    //URL from routes file in Laravel
                    url: 'getquote',
                    //GET request
                    type: 'get',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    data: entries + '&calc_id=' + c_id + '&travelplan=' + plan_name,
                    success: function success(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function error(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                //END AJAX REQUEST
```

**Final controller to use values fetched via the AJAX request above**

```
//Get quotes
    public
    function createQuote(Request $request)
    {

        //Optional validation
        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required|string|min:2',
            'middlename' => 'required|string|min:2',
            'phone' => 'required|string|max:20|regex:/[2547]{4}[0-9]{8}/',
            'dob' => 'required',
        ]);
        //Using GuzzleHttp to post values
        $client = new Client();
        $quote = $client->post(route('api.user.createQuote'), [
            'json' => [
                'FirstName' => $request->firstname,
                'MiddleName' => $request->middlename,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
                'dob' => $request->dob,
            ],
            "http_errors" => false,
        ]);

        dd($quote);
    }
```

Comment: In Ajax file url: 'getquote' change this to url: '/getquote' and print the request values before you post the value

Comment: @Chrisshi I have tried to log the values to see if they are being fetched from the form ,,, seems they aint being fetched